# Excel Group and Match by Product Name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have an excel spreadsheet of product data that I need to be reorganized and grouped by product name. An example of a product name looks like:

`Bee 22"x36" Table Runner, Ecru`

Is there a formula that can find and group all other products with the same name?

For example, I would need the formula to also include

`Bee 22"x48" Table Runner, White`

in the grouped results. It's the same product just a different color and size. I'm thinking I will need to use excel wildcards, but that's all I've got.

**Additional Examples of Products:**

Carillon Pendant Large Ivory 
Carillon Pendant Medium Ivory 
Carillon Pendant Small Ivory
Cashmere Fur Pillow Cream
Cashmere Fur Pillow Light Grey
Focus King Bed
Focus Nightstand
Focus Queen Bed
Focus Sideboard
Godenza Dining Table Rectangular Black Ash
Godenza Dining Table Rectangular Walnut
Godenza Dining Table Round Black Ash
Goldman Statue Large
Goldman Statue Small

Comment: Highly suggest you split the product/color/size into different columns, and then use a pivot table maybe.

Comment: Agree with Ben, you can do this with a couple of iterations of "Text to Columns" depending on your data

Comment: @BigBen the data doesn't split cleanly into different columns by product/color/size due to varying length of the product name. Here's another product name for comparison `Bristol Garden 14x20 Placemat (Set of 4), Cafe` Any advice for this?

Comment: @MichelleM. start small. Text to columns and use the "," to seperate it first, then maybe the " symbols or the "x" etc.

Comment: Consider using the 12 leftmost characters as a key for the sort or populating a helper column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that the structure of a given string is something like: `<manufacturer> <dimensions> <product>, <colour>`.

In other words, in the string `Bee 22"x36" Table Runner, Ecru`:

- `<manufacturer>` = `Bee`
- `<dimensions>` = `22"x36"`
- `<product>` = `Table Runner`
- `<colour>` = `Ecru`

I've also assumed that when you say you want to "group by product name", you want to group by `<product>` (i.e. the text between `<dimensions>` and `<colour>`).

Lastly, I've assumed that it may be better to extract `<product>` first. Thereafter, you can sort/re-organise the rows however you want, since you don't describe in detail the end result you want to achieve.

---

**Using Excel functions and helper columns**

Although `MATCH` offers limited support for wildcards like `*` and `?`, I've not used it. If you have a given string in cell `A2`, try the following:

- in cell `B2`, paste: `=INDEX(SEARCH({"0 ","1 ","2 ","3 ","4 ","5 ","6 ","7 ","8 ","9 "},SUBSTITUTE(A2,"""","")),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"0 ","1 ","2 ","3 ","4 ","5 ","6 ","7 ","8 ","9 "},SUBSTITUTE(A2,"""",""))),0))`
- in cell `C2`, paste: `=SEARCH(" ",MID(A2,1,9999),B2)+1`
- in cell `D2`, paste: `=SEARCH(",",A2)`
- in cell `E2`, paste: `=MID(A2,C2,D2-C2)`

This should give you the extracted `<product>` in cell `E2`.

[image: Non-VBA]

---

**Using VBA and regular expressions**

Instead of the approach above, you could try using VBA (which lets you use regular expressions for more sophisticated/flexible string matching).

1. Open VB Editor (`Alt` + `F11`)
2. `Insert` > `Module`
3. Paste code below in the newly inserted module.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ExtractProduct(ByVal someText As String) As Variant

    Const PRODUCT_PATTERN As String = "\d+["" ]?x ?\d+""? (.+?),"

    Dim regExp As Object
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regExp.Pattern = PRODUCT_PATTERN

    Dim matchesFound As Object
    Set matchesFound = regExp.Execute(someText)

    If matchesFound.Count > 0 Then
        If matchesFound(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
            ExtractProduct = matchesFound(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            ExtractProduct = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        End If
    Else
        ExtractProduct = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
End Function
```

4. Then you should be able to call `ExtractProduct` from the worksheet directly (i.e. assuming cell `A2` contains some input, enter `=ExtractProduct(A2)` in cell `B2`)

---

Unfortunately, built-in worksheet functions in Excel do not currently appear to support regular expressions (compared to something like Google Sheets). So this can't be achieved with just a simple formula -- or at least that's my understanding.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Ambiguous Product Name" when calling ExtractProduct. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichelleM. Check across your VBA code (all sheet modules, `ThisWorkbook` module, custom modules) to see if there is only one variable/function named `ExtractProduct`. The error might be "Ambiguous name detected" (not "Ambiguous Product Name") where "name" refers to the name of the function (`ExtractProduct`) -- and nothing to do with the fact that the function just so happens to extract a product name. If you find more than one `ExtractProduct`, delete/rename/qualify the others (depending on whether you want to keep them). That's all I can say without seeing your Excel file/code.

Comment: Ah ok, I deleted the conflicting VBA module. Now when I run ExtractProduct the result is showing #N/A for all products, despite some of them having a match.

Comment: @MichelleM. Could you give examples of products that are returning `#N/A` but should contain a match? If you could edit as many of them into your question, I'll then check if `PRODUCT_PATTERN` (in the code) can be tweaked.

Comment: I added additional examples of products. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MichelleM. I have bad news for you, I don't think you'll be able to solve this via Excel formulas or regular expressions. The input (for example `Godenza Dining Table Rectangular Black Ash`) is so unstructured that the product (`Dining Table Rectangular`) can only be identified/extracted if you know the meaning of the words and are seeing them in context.

Comment: @MichelleM. Some questions for you to consider. #1 Where are you getting this data from and why is it so unstructured? #2 Can you control/influence its structure to make extracting the product easier? #3 What does the data look like at the source? If it has some structure at the source, maybe it can be collected/captured in a way that preserves that structure?

Comment: thank you for your thoughtful response. Unfortunately I can't control the structure of the data since it is being sent from different vendors. I'm thinking I may need to develop a JavaScript application to perform the necessary tasks, as I'm not familiar with VBA functions and there seems to be limitations on what can be accomplished within Excel. Thanks again :)